# List inside a list in linq - what is it?

Tags: c#, linq

My friends were having discussion on nested lists of objects  in LINQ and when I asked what does that mean, they laughed :(

Can anyone here tell what is nested list. is it same like list inside list? Thank you to all who help me

Is this NestedList?

```
public class X
{
public Y[] y { get; set; }   
}

public class Y
{
int id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like a list inside a list, for example:

```
List<List<int>>
```

It wasn't nice to laugh at you though - it may indicate your code is better organized into logical classes. Such constructs, in general, should be avoided - you probably wouldn't want to expose or use an interface with too complicated types, but it is common to use such lists locally, specially when using LINQ.

A simple example where this can be useful would be:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\");
var files = directories.Select(Directory.GetFiles).ToList();
```

Here, `files` is a `List` holding an array of strings: `List<string[]>`, which is quite similar. It is very likely your friends weren't talking about lists in particular, it is just as common you work with arrays, dictionaries, or `IEnumerable`s.

The posted code does not have nested, or two dimensional lists. X has a array of Y, and that's it. If you has a list of Xs, however, that would have nested lists:

```
IEnumerable<X> xfiles = GetXFiles();
foreach(X file in xfiles)
{
    foreach(Y section in file)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

It comes down to a simple point: an object can hold other objects, with any complexity.

Comment: +1 for the last part, its usually better and more readable to use classes to organize your information rather than nested generic lists

Comment: I wanted an example of a nested list of objects..what does it look like and why do you say it is to be avoided

Comment: @Jasl - added an example and some more details. Remember that "List" and "Object" are general terms, an Enumerable can be seen as a List, and in C# "Object" can describe almost everything you're working with - even functions. Don't look specifically for `List<List<object>>` - that is poor use of generics.

Comment: Nested list looks like this f.e. : List<List<object>>

It should be avoided because the access on the inner object gets harder and the code is not that friendly for other developers

Comment: I was searching the net and saw this  public class X { public Y[] abc { get; set; } } Is this nested list?

Comment: Kobi i have update my question..can you confirm if that is nested list..thank you for help

Comment: So the example i posted will be more of a Parent-Child relationship?

Comment: Yes, if you want to demonstrate nested lists, you need to one extra step of complexity.

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me that what i posted was parent-child. i am now clear with what is a nested list vs parent-child :)

Answer (score 1):

they may mean a List of Lists, such as

```
List<List<String>> listoflists = new List<List<String>>();
listoflists.Add(new List<String>(new string[]{"One","Two"}));
listoflists.Add(new List<String>(new string[]{"A","B","C"}));
```

Comment: You're missing `()` at the constructor. Also, depending on the version of C#, you may simplify it to `listoflists.Add(new List<String> {"One","Two"});`.

Comment: I  wanted an example of a nested list of objects..what does it look like

Comment: @Jasl, this is what it looks like :-)  Just replace "String" with "Object" and there you go.

The nested list is just a list of collections of objects, as outlined in my example